# Why is controller created twice?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Consider following AngularJS app:

- http://jsfiddle.net/pathes/QPL3R/ - application based on tutorial from angularjs.org homepage,
- http://jsfiddle.net/pathes/cUaEv/ - its Jasmine tests.

Method `addPane()` pushes a pane into controller's pane list, `paneCount()` returns its length. After creating 3 panes, accessing method `paneCount()` from binding `{{paneCount()}}` and directly in test: `scope.paneCount()` returns 0.

It appears that AngularJS creates two instances of controller - one accessible from controller methods, another from scope's. Does anybody know why there's a need of creating two instances? Is there a way to access the same properties from both controller and scope methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the controller definition of yours! you defined the scope twice. once in controller itself and once in the directive definition of the tabs directive. the directive definition overrides the scope of the controller and therefore the count will not be correct.

- http://jsfiddle.net/pathes/Z2EWT/ - i've forked your fiddle with the update

`// scope: {}, not necessary because defined in controller ctrl`

hope this helps :)